# Bootstrap thumbnails are not lining up proprerly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap in rails and for some reason my thumbnails are only adding one item to row 2 instead of 4 before starting row three. Here is a screenshot:[image]

Here is my view file:

```
<div id="products_div">
<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron", id= "index">
        <h1>Nature inspired handicrafts and jewelry</h1> 

    </div>

       <% @products.each do |product| %>
        <div class="center-block">
           <div class="col-lg-3">
               <div class = "thumbnail row">
              <%= link_to product do %>
                 <%= image_tag product.image.preview.url, :size => "224.98x178.66" %>
                 <% end %>
             <p><%= product.name[0..30] + "..." %></p>
             <p><%= number_to_currency(product.price, :unit => '$') %></p>
         </div>
        </div>
        </div>
       <% end %>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats because the last block height of the first row is not equal with the first 3. 
Try to use a min-height by 'center-block' class